# variable parameter function - EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling [obj release];

Tags: objective-c-runtime, iphone

I have the following method:

> (void)makeString:(NSString *)str1,... {
>
> ```
>    va_list strings;
>
>    NSString *innerText = [[NSString alloc] init];
>    NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
>
>    if (str1) {
>
>        va_start(strings, str1); 
>
>        while (tmpStr = va_arg(strings, id)) { 
>             innerText = [innerText stringByAppendingString:tmpStr];
>        }
>
>        label.text = [str1 stringByAppendingString:innerText];
>    }
>
>    [tmpStr release];
> ```
>
> }

I will eventually get to Objective C Memory Management reading, where I'm sure I will find the answer to this - probably related to pointers and copying - , but for now, can anyone explain why if I add [innerText release]; as the last line of this function, i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is erroneous.
As far as I can see you are only concatenating the strings to assign the result to `label.text`.
I assume that `label` is an ivar, so `label.text = …` ist legal. Then the following should do it:

```
- (void)makeString: (NSString *)str1, ...
{
   if (str1) {
       NSString *tmpStr;

       va_list strings;
       va_start(strings, str1);
       while (tmpStr = va_arg(strings, id)) {
            str1 = [str1 stringByAppendingString: tmpStr];
       }

       label.text = str1;
   }
}
```

Some notes:

- You should **not** release any input parameter unless your method is about releasing something.
- As the first answer stated, you should not release the result of `stringByAppendingString:` unless
  you have retained it before.

**[Update]**

I changed the answer because it contained an error. `label.text = str1` should retain `str1` of course (if it wants to keep it). Especially the calling code should **not** retain `str1` unless it wants to keep it for itself.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you need to retain str1. Presumably `label` is a `UILabel`, in which case it will retain the contents of `text`.

Answer (score -1):

stringByAppendingString returns an autoreleased string, which is replacing your original assignment. So your release is not needed. But you are leaking memory with the two allocs above.

You should probably use [NSString initWithCString:va_arg(strings, id)] to assign the tmpStr too.

Comment: thanks!  removed the allocs - couldn't get the 

while (tmpStr = [NSString initWithCString:va_arg(strings, id)]) {}

to work.

Comment: Of course you couldn't. `initWithCString:` wants a `char *` and not an `id`. See my answer.

Comment: I think your answer could be more helpful. The release is not “not needed” but wrong as soon as `str1` is not nil. Also `[NSString initWithCString:va_arg(strings, id)]` cannot work. As I explained in my previous comment.